# I need IMG FIT to not resize the images

Tags: html, css, image

Is there any way I can keep the images/cells the same size when the browser is resized/viewed on mobile?

It's absolutely fine when viewed on PCs or Tablets, but the mobile looks terrible with the 5 images staying in one row.
I'd like the mobile version to be 1 image/cell per row.

Here's the HTML

```
<div class="row">
<div class="-1u 2u"> <span class="image fit"><img src="http://thewebster.co/base/images/maskc.png" alt=""></span>

    <p class="align-center">Some Text</p>
</div>
<div class="2u 2u"> <span class="image fit"><img src="http://thewebster.co/base/images/handsc.png" alt=""></span>

    <p class="align-center">Some Text</p>
</div>
<div class="2u 2u"> <span class="image fit"><img src="http://thewebster.co/base/images/safetyc.png" alt=""></span>

    <p class="align-center">Some Text</p>
</div>
<div class="2u 2u"> <span class="image fit"><img src="http://thewebster.co/base/images/gunc.png" alt=""></span>

    <p class="align-center">Some Text</p>
</div>
<div class="2u 2u"> <span class="image fit"><img src="http://thewebster.co/base/images/freedomc.png" alt=""></span>

    <p class="align-center">Some Text</p>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS

```
.row>* {
padding: 0px 0 0 2em;
}
.\-1u {
margin-left: 8.3333333333%;
}
.\32 u, .\32 u\24 {
width: 16.6666666667%;
clear: none;
margin-left: 0;
}
.row>* {
float: left;
}
.image.fit {
display: block;
margin: 0 0 2em 0;
width: 100%;
}
.image {
border-radius: 4px;
border: 0;
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
}
.image.fit img {
width: 100%;
}
image img {
border-radius: 4px;
display: block;
}
.align-center {
text-align: center;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k53mp946/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) to detect the maximum width of the device and remove the floating property (`float: none`) of the rows. This will apply the natural `display: block` and break on each element. Note that the media query below will only override the floating, if the viewport is less than 480px width.

```
@media all and (max-width: 480px) {

    .row > * {
        float: none;
    }

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k53mp946/4/

Comment: Thanks, but could you please explain a little more, I'm not quite sure what and where.

Comment: I edited my post. Media Queries are part of CSS3 and the common way to apply responsiveness, especially on mobile devices.

Comment: I think I'm being thick here, any chance you could add this to the fiddle so I can understand ? Sorry, i feel stupid now.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to MVP's answer, if you're saying that you're seeing 5 images in a row on mobile, I have a suspicion that you might have forgotten to include the following in your head:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1>
```

Alternatively, if you don't want the user to be able to zoom in/out on mobile:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```